JWT signature verification failing
I am trying to implement my own auth using JWT tokens. I generate the jwt tokens in Java Spring boot.
Im using this website to generate a base64 encoded string to be used as the jwt secret: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online?ref=blog.tericcabrel.com
This is the relevant Spring boot code:
private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}

Jwts
        .builder()
        .setClaims(extraClaims)
        .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
        .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
        .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
        .compact();

Which works fine, the problem isnt here. The problem arises on the nextjs side where im trying to verify the jwt token i retrieve from the api after logging in:
export async function verifyAuth() {
  const token = cookies().get('user-token')

  if (!token) {
    return null
  }

  const jwtSecretKey = getJwtSecretKey()

  const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token.value, new TextEncoder().encode(jwtSecretKey))

  return payload as JwtPayload
}

This keeps throwing the following exception, allthough im using the same secret key generated by the website above (getJwtSecretKey just returns the env variable from .env and im using jose):
digest: "3414803446"

⨯ JWSSignatureVerificationFailed: signature verification failed

at async verifyAuth (./lib/auth.ts:74:25)

at async Home (./app/page.tsx:11:18)

What am i doing wrong here?

perhaps getJwtSecretKey() isn't getting the correct secret - you say it does, but maybe it doesn't - how is BASE64.decode(secretKey) the same as new TextEncoder().encode(jwtSecretKey) ... if secretKey and jwtSecretKey are the same base 64 value, then that may explain it

@JaromandaX yeah getJwtSecretKey gets the correct secret, it is the same being using on the backend as secretKey The value is the base64 encoded string i got from the website. I see your point, since im decoding the key on the backend, i should also decode it on the client instead of encoding it right?

no idea ... but BASE64.decode and TextEncoder().encode don't end up with the same result ... perhaps you need to decode the base64 everywhere (no idea what you mean by client, if this is in the browser, you're using JWT wrong)

Why are you using new TextEncoder().encode(jwtSecretKey)? This looks wrong.

Btw, getSignInKey should be spelled getSigningKey

The secret passed in your signing process is decoded from a base64 string before used as the signing secret. You must do the same before passing the secret to jose, otherwise new TextEncoder().encode(jwtSecretKey) just uses the encoded bytes as the secret.
This in Node.js
const secret = Buffer.from(jwtSecretKey, 'base64')

Would be the equivalent of
keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);

